# Run AJAX in an iframe - document.ready not working

Tags: ajax, iframe, facebook-apps

I have an app that uses AJAX, but the AJAX is not working properly in the iframe.

Here is the JS that I am using (this is within the page that is loaded in to the iframe). The 3 functions each call an AJAX routine that populates the App. What I would like is for the iframe to load, and then for this JS to run. It has to be the iframe that calls this code when it has finished loading, as I have no control over the page that loads it (Facebook).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert('HELLO!!!'); // Test to see if it working

    load_tab_content('<?php echo $load_tab_content_nonce; ?>');
    load_services('<?php echo $load_services_nonce; ?>');
    load_pages('<?php echo $load_pages_nonce; ?>');

});
</script>
```

Is this possible, or am I going about it all wrong? Thanks.

Comment: you want to call a function in parent window from the iframe?

Comment: No - I want the iframe to call a function from itself when it has finished loading - document.ready() is firing my functions too early, so the content of the App is not loading. Facebook Apps are loaded in an iframe, so everything has to be done by the App, and all 'how to' docs that I can find suggest you need the parent to be able to do it. Thanks.

Comment: document.ready is different from window.load while document ready fire your script early when the components are ready to use, the window.load wait till everything finish loading. try to use window.load

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go now...

Comment: ...Sadly not the answer.

Comment: maybe if you post some script. what are you doing in the iFrame?

Comment: I've added some to the question, let me know if you require more.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to run the 3 functions when the Facebook (parent) page finish loading?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery into the iframe as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend one of two ways to accomplish this, the first and probably easiest is to just run the onload function in the parent page.  You're probably not going to get the onReady in the iframe document to execute properly.

```
<script>
  function notify_load() {
    //alert("now do something");
  }
</script>

<iframe src="http://someurl/" onload="notify_loaded()" />
```

The second suggestion is to write a script in the iframe page that changes a variable that can be queried from the main page.  Or you might even want to try calling a parent page function directly ie. parent.notify_load();